# Styling un-ordered list based on the list value

Tags: html, css, list

I am stuck on a list issue, not sure how to attack it.

Code is as follows

```
<ul>
    <li class="even even typeTextfield group2">
    <span class="itemExtraFieldsLabel">Phone:</span>
    <span class="itemExtraFieldsValue">12345678</span>
    </li>
    <li class="odd type link group2">
    <span class="itemExtraFieldsLabel">Facebook:</span>
    <span class="itemExtraFieldsValue"><a href="http://www.facebook.com target="_blank">Facebook</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to basically replace the word Phone and Facebook next to the itemExtraFieldsLabel class with an image.  I understand that I can do something with CSS and Javascript, but can't seem to get it working.

The code is generated by a plugin, and the site is being built with Joomla, if that makes any difference.

Any help and guidance for a learner would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `<li>` are not closing in the code

Comment: Sorry @VitorinoFernandes, thats my fault.  The actual code on the site does have closing </li>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use **[background-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image)** property to set background to **span** item.

If you can't change the **html** code to add unique **class** for each element, you could use **[:nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)** to target each element by it's order.

So you final css would be:

```
ul .group2:nth-child(1) .itemExtraFieldsLabel {
  background-image: url('phone.png');
}
ul .group2:nth-child(2) .itemExtraFieldsLabel {
  background-image: url('facebook.png');
}
```

For text hiding there are many solutions.
You could use `font-size:0px`, `text-indent: -9999px;` or [something else that would fit your needs](http://css-tricks.com/css-image-replacement/).

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @emmanuel, but it doesn't appear to work.  Have tried it numerous ways.  Will keep playing and see where I end up.

Comment: It doesn't load the image or the class is not getting applied?

Comment: both, nothing is happening.

Comment: If the classes are not applied, then you have added them in a wrong file. Please try to clear browser and joomla cache after your addition.

Comment: Ok, got it working now.  Discovered that there was actually some other list items above the code, so actually they are nth-child 3 & 4 not 1 & 2.  Thanks for all your help @emmanuel.